# C# Page.FindControl returns null on dynamic controls

Tags: c#, asp.net, dynamic-controls

I have two pages on which I bound *dynamic controls* . All the controls what I bound are **TextBox**es. Whenever I tried to retrieve the values of the controls in first page using

```
Page.Findcontrol("ctl00$cph_cabFest$AccountNumber")
```

It gives the proper result. But the second page gives the result as NULL. What could be the exact issue? Could anyone suggest me some way to identify this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just take a look at your *event cycle*. The best way to overcome these kind of issues is to bind the controls in Page_Init as well. 
    There might be another reason for this. Bind your `Panel` in each PostBack request.

Comment: I tried to bind the controls in Page_Init(). But still it doesn't works :(

Comment: Thankx Rahul. That is the reason. I bound controls in !PostBack request. Now it is working fine..:)